# How to trim directory from which output without basename?

Tags: busybox, cygwin, which, basename

For a shell script I need to call an executable by name, regardless of the path leading there; thus far I know this code reports the right name:

```
tmpprog=`which program`
prog=${tmpprog%%*/}
if $prog=""
then
  echo >&2 "Main Program not found"
else
  echo >&2 "$prog"
fi
```

How can I cut the code so that I may trim the path to keep the executable name and remove the path in a one liner?

Beware: `basename` won't do it, since I may be working on a hybrid environment (cygwin/busybox on windoze), and sometimes the paths have spaces.

Comment: Just run `program` directly? Why go to this effort of finding where `program` is located to then discard that information?

Comment: I'm running a test so that, if finding the program fails, I may fallback to a substitute procedure; and as I said, I cannot rely on the consistency of how to handle paths in a hybrid environment.

Comment: Ok, but that still doesn't explain why you need to do anything with the path at all. Fallback to substitute procedure or do whatever if the test fails, but if the test succeeds, just run `program` instead of messing around with the path. In your code, that'd be like: `if ! command -v program > /dev/null; then echo >&2 "Main Program not found"; else echo >&2 program; fi`

Comment: What does `if $prog=""` do? Have you tried it with various values of `prog`? Why do you say you can't use `basename` due to spaces in the paths?

Comment: @ilkkachu: Iʻm checking whether there is anything left after trimming the directory part...

Comment: @muru: thatʻs the point: Iʻd like to know how get only the program name, without having to go all around the directory trimming after calling `which`, and avoiding the pitfall of a space in a path in a windoze directory with `basename`.

Comment: btw, chazelas is right: Iʻm just trying to check wheter `program` is available or not, to proceed accordingly...

Comment: But you already have the program name.

Comment: indeed: the idea is to run these tests and tell the user what went wrong, if anything...

Comment: @jarnosz, ok, you don't have to answer the questions.

Comment: for context: I was trying to run `pdfroff`, which is a shell script, on busybox on windoze, and the script could not find windoze's `gswin64c` because the path has a space in it. By inspecting the code, I found a baroque function `searchpath()` which does some checking, and reports installation errors to the user. For most *ix people this must be very weird, but makes sense as the script was designed to run on either OS, but not in a hybrid system. Now I see that `hash` does the job, and that the script needs indeed some simplification.

Comment: @jarnosz if that's all, then again: why do you need to manipulate the path to tell the user something went wrong? You'd only get the path if things __didn't__ go wrong, and at that point you can just use the command name instead of the path.

Comment: that's not all at all: at some point, the script has to query which version of GhostScript is running, and that depends on the OS (gs or gswin64c on modern machines, nix or win; but also gswin32c or even gsos2 for historical reasons: and I fear a similar check should be done with awk, as there are several implementations), so `searchpath` has to determine not only that the program exists, but also the name under which it is available...

Comment: Eh, what? You're using the name to find out where the program is, and then you turn around and say now you need to determine what that name was?

Comment: as I said, it's not my code: I'm trying to patch this script. it also looks odd to me, so that's why I am asking how to avoid going all this weird way around: how to determine under which name a program is available, if any, to act accordingly, withouth having to strip the path.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like all you need is to check whether `program` is available as a command, then:

```
#! /bin/sh -
hash program || exit

# use program now:
program with its args
```

I'm using [`hash`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/hash.html) instead of `command -v > /dev/null` as `hash` will report an error if `program` can't be found saving having to do it yourself. In any case, [you don't want to use `which`](/q/85249).

Comment: how could I issue an error/warning or call a fallback procedure after the failure of `hash program`? afaik, `exit` will simply bail out without further ado.